# Create email template in Lotus notes 7

Tags: lotus-notes

Is it possible to create an email template in Lotus Notes?
I need to send very often an email that contains a fixed structure (subject, body), with slight variations, and it would be useful to be able to store a template email that I can reuse.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called **Stationery**

Create a new memo, with the structure/look you want, then use the tools dropdown to save as stationary

[image: picture of new memo tools dropdown]

When you want to use that memo, select **New memo - Using Stationery** from the tools menu of your inbox

[image: picture of inbox tools dropdown]

Comment: You can access the stationary via the "tools" button in the left hand menu